# AWS Load Balancer

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2

I have created WebApi in Mvc .net , where i am using `Microsoft.OWIN` for authentication and access token generation and hosting my APIs in AWS.

Now , as am using load balancer to distribute the traffic , so AWS automatically generates multiple instance of the EC2 instance that means multiple servers , so when and where the Login Api is called , the request goes to one main server and generated the Token and in `Claims Identity` , we are storing `UserID` of that Logged IN User , but when another APIs are called simultaneously to multiple instances randomly, then that `UserID` which is stored while login in `Claims Identity` is not accessible from other randomly generated servers.

So, I dont know whether it Owin issue or AWS load Balancer issue , is there functionality in AWS or OWIN , so that UserID will be accessible from multiple server?

and I can't remove OWIN from my API.

Comment: You either need to setup distributed sessions somehow (I have no idea how to do that with the technologies you are using) or enable session stickiness in your load balancer.

Comment: Yes i added Sticky Sessions in aws but it won't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a central session store, something like Redis or a central DB. I have seen both used by different applications and I am sure there are other methods available to act as a central point for all sessions.

Comment: I am in doubt about Redis that it will work with OWIN or not , but i guess this is the last option for me.